# nixos-option for NixOps deployed machine?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixops

There is a command `nixos-option` which examines given system's option value. Under the hood it does something like:

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E '
  let nixos = import <nixpkgs/nixos> { };
      opt = nixos.config.networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts;
  in builtins.deepSeq opt opt
  '

$-> [ 1194 22 8081 80 443 4949 ]
```

But that doesn't work for NixOps deployed machines (configuration isn't available there). Is there a way to get option value from NixOps deploment config, on deployer machine?

Comment: The `show-option` sub command to nixops gives you deployment attributes from the deployer machine, or do you want to be able to access them from the _deployed_ machine? In which case I'm not aware of a builtin way of doing that since as you say the configs are only on the deployer machine, not the deployed machine (though it could be good feature to add)

Comment: much thanks! I wanted to access option on deployer machine, yes.
I'd like to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nixops has [the solution](http://nixos.org/nixops/manual/#sec-nixops)! ;)

> Command nixops show-option
>
> Synopsis
>
> nixops show-option [--xml] machine option
>
> Description
>
> This command prints the value of the specified NixOS configuration option for the specified machine.